# How to push logs to elasticsearch in filebeat instantly?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

hear is my filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - ../typescript/rate-limit-test/logs/*.log
  json.message_key: "message"
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.overwrite_keys: true
  scan_frequency: 1s

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1

logging.level: debug

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["34.97.108.113:9200"]
  index: "filebeat-%{+yyyy-MM-dd}"
setup.template:
  name: 'filebeat'
  pattern: 'filebeat-*'
  enabled: true
setup.template.overwrite: true
setup.template.append_fields:
- name: time
  type: date

processors:
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["agent","host","ecs","input","log"]

setup.ilm.enabled: false`
```

I changed scan_frequncy but elasticsearch couldn't get logs faster

How can i get logs in elasticsearch instantly?

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be never an 'instantly' available logline in elasticsearch. The file needs to be watched for a considerable amount of changes or time, then the newly added lines need to be sent to elasticsearch in a bulk request and indexed into the appropriate shard on the correct cluster node. Network latency, TLS, authentification + authorization, concurrent write/search load: all the things affects the 'instantly' experience.

The speed of log ingestion and NRT (near-real-time search) depends on many factors and configuration options in elasticsearch and filebeat.

Regarding tuning elasticsearch for indexing speed, have a look at [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html), and apply what you have missed yet. A brief overview:

- Disable swapping and enable memory locking (`bootstrap.memory_lock: true`)
- Consider reducing `index.refresh_interval` (defaults to 1s) for the index in order to have the docs flushed more often (produces more IO in the cluster)

For Filebeat, [there is also good documentation about tuning](https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/how-to-tune-elastic-beats-performance-a-practical-example-with-batch-size-worker-count-and-more), but in general, I see the following options:

- Try different `output.elasticsarch.bulk_max_size` values (defaults to a batch size of 50) and monitor the ingestion speed. For each cluster configuration, there are different optimal settings.
- In high load scenarios, when the logs are written fast, consider increasing the number of workers `output.elasticsarch.workers` (defaults to 1)
- In the opposite scenario, having just a few log lines being written, consider increasing the [`close_inactive`](https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/how-to-tune-elastic-beats-performance-a-practical-example-with-batch-size-worker-count-and-more) and [`scan_frequency`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-input-log.html) value for the harvester. Specifying a more suitable `backoff` will have an effect on how aggressively Filebeat checks files for updates.